# Laravel 5.5. Missing required parameters for [Route: password.request]

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have the following in my **route**:

```
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.request');
```

My **reset.blade** under auth is looks like

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Reset Password</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ $email or old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Reset Password
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I tried to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/administrator/password/reset/2dfc0ea2306e3d60dcc915b26cefc8779921bf99183084b3d765cf0a348f32c6 , it show me the error;

> Missing required parameters for [Route: password.request] [URI:
>   administrator/password/reset/{token}]. (View:
>   /var/www/html/shoptomydoor/resources/views/auth/passwords/reset.blade.php)

Comment: Its written right in the error, you are not providing token when generating the url via `route(...)`, it should be `route('password.request', ['token' => $token])`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its written right in the error, you are not providing token when generating the URL via route(...), it should be `route('password.request', ['token' => $token])` as answered in comments. 
change to this. Go to your template page and then add the code below to your form tag action.

```
action="{{ route('password.request', ['token' => $token]) }}"
```

because you are passing a token in your get parameter

```
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.request');
```

Comment: All okay now. Sorry!

Comment: @KuldeepMishra original post should be deleted instead, OP failed to understand the error and asked what it means.