# Credentials method failing on laravel

Tags: database, laravel, web, forgot-password, password-recovery

I am trying to make a switcher in my website (made in laravel), i have solved a lot of problems and at now, i am getting error at the function

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only('email');

    }
```

My paths are like: localhost/es/password/email
I attach the code, thank you.

email.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Reset Password') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route( 'password.email', app()->getLocale()) }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Send Password Reset Link') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

web.php

```
Route::redirect('/', '/en');

Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}',
            'where' => ['language' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}']],
             function(){
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

    Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

    Route::get('/projects', 'projectsController@create')->name('projects');
    Route::post('/createProject', 'projectsController@store'); 
    Route::post('/modifyProject/{id}', 'projectsController@update'); 
    Route::get('/projects/{id}/delete', 'projectsController@destroy');

    Auth::routes();
    Route::get('/logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');

});
```

If you need something more of my app, say to this post and i will paste into in.
Regards

Comment: You might tell us what the error *says*?

Comment: Yes sorry, the error is **Missing required parameters for [Route: password.reset] [URI: {language}/password/reset/{token}]. **

Comment: I think your question is the same with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232314/laravel-5-5-missing-required-parameters-for-route-password-request). Hope this can help you

Comment: Yes is similar, but i think that not's the same, this is happening me after setting up the localization, so, i think that should be about pass the locale parameter, but i think that i am doing that at these lane:  <form method="POST" action="{{ route( 'password.email', app()->getLocale()) }}">, following the post you tiped, i should write  <form method="POST" action="{{ route( 'password.email', app()->getLocale(), 'hash' => $hash) }}">   ??? Thanks to all

Comment: dont worked neither..

Answer (score 0):

I have seemed that if i change the credentials functions to:

```
 protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        //dd($request);
        return $request->only('email', '#defaultLocale');
    }
```

the response of

```
  $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $this->credentials($request)
        );
```

is passwords.throttle, and should be passwords.sent